# How does RSA decryption work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, rsa

I followed the [wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Example) to implement it and I am using mathjs to get around the infinity problems the Math library has. My encrypted value was the same as wikipedias the last time I checked, but decryption doesn’t work. I don‘t plan on using my implementation. This is only for learning purposes.

```js
import { lcm } from './lcm.js';
import { create, all } from 'mathjs';

// instantiate math.js
const config = {};
const math = create(all, config);

// choose two large prime numbers
const p = 61;
const q = 53;

// calculate n
const n = p * q;

// compute least common multiple of p - 1 and q - 1
const phi = lcm(p - 1, q - 1);
console.log(`phi(n) = ${phi}`);

// choose a number e such that 1 < e < phi(n) and gcd(e, phi(n)) = 1
const e = 17;

// calculate d such that d * e = 1 mod phi(n)
const d = math.invmod(e, phi);
console.log(`d = ${d}`)

// print public key
console.log(`Public key: (${e}, ${n})`);

function encryptMessage(message) {
    // encrypt message using public key
    const encryptedMessage = math.mod(math.pow(math.bignumber(message), math.bignumber(e)), math.bignumber(n));

    // print encrypted message
    console.log(`Encrypted message: ${encryptedMessage}`);
    return encryptedMessage;
}

function decryptMessage(message) {
    console.log(message, d, n)
    // decrypt message using private key
    const decryptedMessage = math.mod(math.pow(math.bignumber(message), math.bignumber(d)), math.bignumber(n));
    console.log(math.pow(math.bignumber(message), math.bignumber(d)))

    // print decrypted message
    console.log(`Decrypted message: ${decryptedMessage}`);
}

// encrypt and decrypt message
decryptMessage(encryptMessage(12));
```

I expect the output to be twelve, but its not. Can you help me figure out why?

Comment: You didn't follow step 5 to calculate the modular multiplicative inverse. You just hardcoded an incorrect value

Comment: If you change `p` to `61` it should work

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

// calculate d such that d*e=1 mod phi(n)

```
const d = math.modInv(e, phi);
```

Comment: I think the method is called invmod(). After changing my code to the above it still does not return the correct output.